# Multiple arrays mapping angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

Trying to add two arrays in jquery `each` method and trying to display different text based on the logic.

I have two arrays, demo and catID. Demo array is working fine where as coming to catID array the jquery `.each` is not working properly it still returning an array. Thats the the condition is failing it is failing to find out the exact matched value from the array. Can anyone help me out?

JS:

```
    function App( ){
                var Label = ‘a’;
        var KeyLabel = 'cat'; 
                var demo = [“a”,”b”,’c’,’d’];
                var CatID =['1','2','3'];
scatID='1';
                jQuery.each( [demo,CatID], function( index, value) {
                    debugger;
                    if((Label==value)&&(scatID==CatID)){
                        debugger;
                        $scope.snewText = 'Hello from A';
                        $scope.scatText = 'Cat ID';
                    }
                });
            }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5U5Jh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what do you want ? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5U5Jh/1/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    var Label = 'a';
    var KeyLabel = 'cat';
    var demo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    var CatID = ['1', '2', '3'];
    scatID = '1';
    angular.forEach(demo, function (value, index) {

        if (Label == value) {

            $scope.snewText = 'Hello from A';
            $scope.scatText = 'Cat ID';
        }
    });

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i can't find that definition of each at any place in the jquery docs

http://api.jquery.com/each/

not to mention that angular has its own foreach more suited for this type of things

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

if what you are trying to do is checking if both Label and scatID belong to the same index you would be better off doing something like

```
    if(catID.indexOf(scatID)===demo.indexOf(label)){
           $scope.snewText = 'Hello from A';
           $scope.scatText = 'Cat ID';
     }
```

Comment: Here is the documentation for jQuery.each he is trying to use: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/